# Why I have a connection refused error when starting rabbit by docker-compose?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, rabbitmq, ldap

I run sprinboot app, front (in react), database and rabbitmq in docker-compose. When I run it everything works except rabbitmq. I had an error - "Connection refused".

docker-compose:

```
version:  '3'
services:
    server:
      build: ./mlogger
      ports:
      - "8000:8080"
      depends_on:
      - database
      restart: always
    web:
      build: ./web
      ports:
      - "4000:3000"
      tty: true
      depends_on:
      - server
    database:
      container_name: 'mysql'
      image: mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: jitsi1234
        MYSQL_USER: jitsiteam
        MYSQL_DATABASE: testmlogger
      ports:
      - "3306:3306"
      restart: always
    rabbitmq:
      image: rabbitmq:3-management
      container_name: rabbitmq
      command: sh -c "rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap"
      ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
      restart: always
```

error:

```
server_1    | 2020-09-05 16:14:42.110  INFO 6 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
server_1    | 2020-09-05 16:14:42.117 ERROR 6 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).
server_1    | 
server_1    | org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
server_1    |   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
server_1    |   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:524) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
server_1    |   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:751) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
server_1    |   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:214) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
server_1    |   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2089) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
server_1    |   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2062) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
server_1    |   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2042) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
server_1    |   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueInfo(RabbitAdmin.java:407) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
server_1    |   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:391) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
server_1    |   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.attemptDeclarations(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1836) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
server_1    |   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1817) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
server_1    |   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1349) [spring-rabbit-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
server_1    |   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1195) [spring-rabbit-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
server_1    |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_265]
server_1    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
server_1    |   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
server_1    |   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
server_1    |   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
server_1    |   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
server_1    |   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
server_1    |   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
server_1    |   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60) ~[amqp-client-5.9.0.jar!/:5.9.0]
server_1    |   at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1137) ~[amqp-client-5.9.0.jar!/:5.9.0]
server_1    |   at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1087) ~[amqp-client-5.9.0.jar!/:5.9.0]
server_1    |   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connectAddresses(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:560) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
server_1    |   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:533) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
server_1    |   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:487) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.7.RELEASE]
server_1    |   ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Spring boot properties:

```
spring.rabbitmq.address=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
```

I'm using ldap also, and I want to add users to rabbitmq on start. I can do it by adding commands to docker-compose?

Spring boot ldap config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableLdapRepositories
public class LdapConfig {

    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
        LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl("ldap://localhost:18889");
        contextSource.setBase("dc=example,dc=com");
        return contextSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSource());
    }
}
```

Comment: The `command:` you provide to the `rabbitmq` container runs _instead of_ the normal command: you're adding plugins, then exiting immediately, instead of running the message broker.  You might need a custom derived image to add the plugins; see "Enabling Plugins" on the [Docker Hub `rabbitmq` page](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, in the docker compose part responsible for the spring application, I had to specify the **network mode**:

```
server:
 build: ./mlogger
 ports:
  - "8000:8080"
 depends_on:
  - database
  - rabbitmq
 network_mode: "host"
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside a container, `localhost` is the container itself, not the host it is running on. Components are visible to each other with their service names. Insead of connecting to localhost:5672, connect to rabbitmq:5672, and it should work. Do the same for the database as well.

Comment: I did it with the database before, I forgot about the rabbit, but still the same error

Comment: Same error meaning is it still complaining about not being able to connect to localhost?

Comment: no, rabbit turns on, I can log in with guest guest, but when the spring boot app tries to connect, this error is displayed (server_1 is spring boot app)

Comment: that's what I asked: does the error say localhost? Right before the error dump, it says it is connecting to localhost

Comment: indeed, my app try to connect by localhost even when I change address to rapid, how to change it?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe config is not where is should be? Maybe address is hardcoded?